# Searching in a .txt file and Comparing the two values of a string in python?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, python-3.x, ipython

```
"cadence_regulatable_result": "completeRecognition",
    "appserver_results": {
        "status": "success",
        "final_response": 0,
        "payload": {
            "actions": [{
                "speaker": "user",
                "type": "conversation",
                "nbest_text": {
                    "confidences": [478,
                    0,
                    0],
                    "words": [[{
                        "stime": 0,
                        "etime": 1710,
                        "word": "ConnectedDrive\\*no-space-before",
                        "confidence": "0.241"
                    }],
                    [{
                        "stime": 0,
                        "etime": 1020,
                        "word": "Connected\\*no-space-before",
                        "confidence": "0.0"
                    },
                    {
                        "stime": 1020,
                        "etime": 1710,
                        "word": "drive",
                        "confidence": "0.0"
                    }],
                    [{
                        "stime": 0,
                        "etime": 900,
                        "word": "Connect\\*no-space-before",
                        "confidence": "0.0"
                    },
                    {
                        "stime": 900,
                        "etime": 980,
                        "word": "to",
                        "confidence": "0.0"
                    },
                    {
                        "stime": 980,
                        "etime": 1710,
                        "word": "drive",
                        "confidence": "0.0"
                    }]],
                    "transcriptions"= ["ConnectedDrive",
                    "Connected drive",
                    "Connect to drive"]
                }
            }]
        }
    },
    "final_response": 0,
    "prompt": "",
    "result_format": "appserver_post_results"
}: form-data;name="QueryResult"Content-Type: application/JSON;charset=utf-8Nuance-Context: efb3d3ce-ef50-4e83-8c31-063c3f5208aa{
    "status_code": 0,
    "result_type": "DRAGON_NLU_ASR_CMD",
    "NMAS_PRFX_SESSION_ID": "f786f0be-d547-4fca-8d72-96429a30c9db",
    "NMAS_PRFX_TRANSACTION_ID": "1",
    "audio_transfer_info": {
        "packages": [{
            "time": "20151221085512579",
            "bytes": 1633
        },
        {
            "time": "20151221085512598",
            "bytes": 3969
        }],
        "nss_server": "10.56.11.186:4503",
        "end_time": "20151221085512596",
        "audio_id": 1,
        "start_time": "20151221085512303"
    },
    "cadence_regulatable_result": "completeRecognition",
    "appserver_results": {
        "status": "success",
        "final_response": 1,
        "payload": {
            "diagnostic_info": {
                "adk_dialog_manager_status": "undefined",
                "nlu_version": "[NLU_PROJECT:NVCCP-eng-USA];[D0160932];[VL-Models:Version: vl.1.100.12-2-GMT20151130160335]",
                "nlps_host": "mt-dmz-nlps002.nuance.com:8636",
                "nlps_ip": "10.56.10.51",
                "application": "AUDI_2017",
                "nlu_component_flow": "[Input:VoiceJSON] [FieldID|auto_main] [NLUlib|C-eckart-r$Rev$.f20151118.1250] [build|G-r72490M.f20151130.1055] [vlmodel|Version: 2-GMT20151130160335] [Flow|+VlingoTokenized]",
                "third_party_delay": "0",
                "nmaid": "AUDI_SDS_2017_EXT_20151203",
                "nlps_profile": "AUDI_2017",
                "fieldId": "auto_main",
                "nlps_profile_package_version": "r159218",
                "nlu_annotator": "com-GBR.ncs51.VlingoNLU-client-qNVCCP_NCS51",
                "ext_map_time": "2",
                "nlu_use_literal_annotator": "0",
                "int_map_time": "2",
                "nlps_nlu_type": "nlu_project",
                "nlu_language": "eng-GBR",
                "timing": {
                    "finalRespSentDelay": "188",
                    "intermediateRespSentDelay": "648"
                },
                "nlps_profile_package": "AUDI_2017"
            },
            "actions": [{
                "Input": {
                    "Interpretations": ["ConnectedDrive"],
                    "Type": "asr"
                },
                "Instances": [{
                    "nlu_classification": {
                        "Domain": "UDE",
                        "Intention": "Unspecified"
                    },
                    "nlu_interpretation_index": 1,
                    "nlu_slot_details": {
                        "Name": {
                            "literal": "ConnectedDrive"
                        },
                        "Search-phrase": {
                            "literal": "connecteddrive"
                        }
                    },
                    "interpretation_confidence": 4549
                }],
                "type": "nlu_results",
                "api_version": "1.0"
            }],
            "nlps_version": "nlps(z):6.1.100.12.2-B359;Version: nlps-base-GMT20151130193521;"
        }
    },
```

Firstly, I am searching for transcriptions and interpretations word in the .txt file (So I am using regex) then I want to compare the FIRST value of transcriptions ("Drive me to a charging station") with the Interpreations value ("Drive me to a charging station"). If I give as below in my program, it is just printing as Recognition is INVALID

```
directory =os.path.join("C:\Users\hemanth_venkatappa\Desktop\Working\pcm-audio\English")
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(directory): 
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".txt"): 
            content=json.load(file)
            if "status_code" in content:
                if content["status_code"]==0:
                    print("valid")
```

Comment: Can you show what the rest of the data file contains.

Comment: Sorry,  meant the data file.

Comment: The .txt file is huge. I cant put it here.

Comment: Looks very similar JSON or even Python source. Just woundering if the whole file looks like this.

Comment: I modified my code. added most of my text file. Can you please see once ?

Comment: `"status_code"` should be a key in content dict if you want to use `if "status_code" in content`.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at `difflib` for text comparison using Python.

> The difflib module contains tools for computing and working with
>   differences between sequences. It is especially useful for comparing
>   text, and includes functions that produce reports using several common
>   difference formats.
>
> [difflib tutorial](https://pymotw.com/2/difflib/)

Using this module you can evaluate differences between two strings or `.txt` files this way:

```
import difflib

a = ["Drive me to a charging station", "Drive me to charging station", "Drive me to a charging Station"]
correct = ["Drive me to a charging station"]

print difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, a[0], correct[0]).ratio()
>> 1.0

print difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, a[1], correct[0]).ratio()
>> 0.965517241379

print difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, a[2], correct[0]).ratio()
>> 0.966666666667
```

As you can see, the `.ratio()` between `a[0]` and `correct` is 1.0 or 100%. This means they're the same string.

You can use a `loop` to `evaluate the ratios` and `if ratio == 1.0` then `print "Recognition is VALID "`

Also if you don't wanna use the `.ratio(`) between the strings, you can check the differences using:

```
d = difflib.Differ()
diff = d.compare(a, correct)
print '\n'.join(diff)
```

And this block of code gives me:

```
  Drive me to a charging          # no signal at the start means it's the same string
- Drive me to charging station    # this string has less chars than the expected string
- Drive me to a charging Station  # same here
```

Then you'll have to figure a way to print `Recognition is VALID or INVALID` according to your expectations.

Comment: thanks for the reply. But Firstly , I want to parse the .txt file to find a, correct (In my case : Interpretations and transcriptions) then I have to compare. How to do that w.r.t your suggestion ?

Comment: Your `a` and `corrects` strings are inside the same `.txt`?

Comment: I modified my code as above. But It is showing error as : 'transcriptions' is not defined

Comment: Change `"transcriptions": ["str1","str2","str3"]`  to `transcriptions = ["str1","str2","str3"]`. Also I would change `a=f.read()` to `a=f.readlines()`. So instead of a `transcriptions = ["string1\nstring2\nstring3\n"]` I would have `transcriptions = ["string1", "string2", "string3"]`

Comment: No I cant change that .txt file content because it is a response from the server. So I have to parse that file and compare those two strings.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be JSON. You should be able to load the whole file into a dictionary with:

```
import json
data = json.load(f)
```

Now `data` contains a dictionary of other dictionaries and lists. You need to find your way through by exploring the dictionary.

Similar to this:

```
interpretations = data["appserver_results"]["actions"][0]["Input"]["Interpretations"] 
transcriptions = (data["cadence_regulatable_result"]["completeRecognition"]["appserver_results"]
                  ["payload"]["actions"][0]["nbest_text"]["transcriptions"])
```

You need to adjust to your real data. Play around at the interactive prompt to find find out what keys and indices you need to use.

Now you check if it is contained:

```
if interpretations[0] in transcriptions:
    print('found', interpretations[0] )
```

You final program can look similar to this:

```
def find_interpretations(fobj):
    data = json.load(fobj)
    interpretations = data["appserver_results"]["actions"][0]["Input"]["Interpretations"] 
    transcriptions = (data["cadence_regulatable_result"]["completeRecognition"]["appserver_results"]
              ["payload"]["actions"][0]["nbest_text"]["transcriptions"])
    if interpretations[0] in transcriptions:
        return interpretations[0]
    return None

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(directory): 
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".txt"): 
            file_name = os.path.join(subdir, file)
            with open(file_name) as fobj:
                found = find_interpretations(fobj)
                if found:
                    print('found: {} in file: {}'.format(found, file_name)
```

Comment: The below two lines, reads the .txt file but The problem is how to compare the interpretation and transcription content or values ? f=open(os.path.join(subdir, file),'r')
            a=f.read()

Comment: I modified the code based on your suggestion but it is not working.I am getting the error as : if Interpretations[0] in transcriptions:
NameError: name 'Interpretations' is not defined

Comment: It is lower case: `interpretations[0]`.

Comment: interpreations in my .txt file is in CAPITAL letter (I). so I did like that and I tried the small letter also : if interpretations[0] in transcriptions:
NameError: name 'interpretations' is not defined

Comment: Use the name you use here `interpretations = data["appserver_results"]["actions"][0]["Input"]["Interpretations"] `. This one `interpretations =`

Comment: sorry. Changed the code as above and getting the error as :  data = json.load(f)
  File "C:\Python27_3\lib\json\__init__.py", line 278, in load
    **kw)
  File "C:\Python27_3\lib\json\__init__.py", line 326, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python27_3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python27_3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 384, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

Comment: Looks like there is something wrong with the JSON. Check that you copied all data  into the file.

Answer (score 0):

Since the tries with `difflib` and `json` led you nowhere, this is based on your original approach from revision 2 of your question; it basically just uses `re.search` instead of `re.findall` to check whether the first transcription equals the interpretation:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import re
directory = os.path.join("../data/English")
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(directory): 
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".txt"): 
            f = open(os.path.join(subdir, file),'r')
            a = f.read() 
            if re.findall('\"status_code\": 0', a):
                print('Status is Valid') 
            else:
                print('Status is Invalid')
            m = re.search('"transcriptions"= ."(.*)"', a)
            if m and re.search('"Interpretations": ."'+m.group(1), a):
                print('Recognition is VALID')
            else:
                print('Recognition is INVALID')
```