# Finding a variable in the .txt and comparing the values within two variables?

Tags: python, regex

```
----bDdefsYG3wqContent-Disposition: form-data;name="QueryResult"Content-Type: application/JSON;charset=utf-8-Context: efb3d3ce-ef50-4e83-8c31-063c3f5208aa{
    "status_code": 0,
    "result_type": "DRAGON_NLU_ASR_CMD",
    "NMAS_PRFX_SESSION_ID": "f786f0be-d547-4fca-8d72-96429a30c9db",
    "NMAS_PRFX_TRANSACTION_ID": "1",
    "audio_transfer_info": {
        "packages": [{
            "time": "20151221085512579",
            "bytes": 1633
        },
        {
            "time": "20151221085512598",
            "bytes": 3969
        }],
        "nss_server": "10.56.11.186:4503",
        "end_time": "20151221085512596",
        "audio_id": 1,
        "start_time": "20151221085512303"
    },
    "cadence_regulatable_result": "completeRecognition",
    "appserver_results": {
        "status": "success",
        "final_response": 0,
        "payload": {
            "actions": [{
                "speaker": "user",
                "type": "conversation",
                "nbest_text": {
                    "confidences": [478,
                    0,
                    0],
                    "words": [[{
                        "stime": 0,
                        "etime": 1710,
                        "word": "ConnectedDrive\\*no-space-before",
                        "confidence": "0.241"
                    }],
                    [{
                        "stime": 0,
                        "etime": 1020,
                        "word": "Connected\\*no-space-before",
                        "confidence": "0.0"
                    },
                    {
                        "stime": 1020,
                        "etime": 1710,
                        "word": "drive",
                        "confidence": "0.0"
                    }],
                    [{
                        "stime": 0,
                        "etime": 900,
                        "word": "Connect\\*no-space-before",
                        "confidence": "0.0"
                    },
                    {
                        "stime": 900,
                        "etime": 980,
                        "word": "to",
                        "confidence": "0.0"
                    },
                    {
                        "stime": 980,
                        "etime": 1710,
                        "word": "drive",
                        "confidence": "0.0"
                    }]],
                    "transcriptions"= ["ConnectedDrive",
                    "Connected drive",
                    "Connect to drive"]
                }
            }]
        }
    },
    "final_response": 0,
    "prompt": "",
    "result_format": "appserver_post_results"
}-Disposition: form-data;name="QueryResult"Content-Type: application/JSON;charset=utf-8-Context: efb3d3ce-ef50-4e83-8c31-063c3f5208aa{
    "status_code": 0,
    "result_type": "DRAGON_NLU_ASR_CMD",
    "NMAS_PRFX_SESSION_ID": "f786f0be-d547-4fca-8d72-96429a30c9db",
    "NMAS_PRFX_TRANSACTION_ID": "1",
    "audio_transfer_info": {
        "packages": [{
            "time": "20151221085512579",
            "bytes": 1633
        },
        {
            "time": "20151221085512598",
            "bytes": 3969
        }],
        "nss_server": "10.56.11.186:4503",
        "end_time": "20151221085512596",
        "audio_id": 1,
        "start_time": "20151221085512303"
    },
    "cadence_regulatable_result": "completeRecognition",
    "appserver_results": {
        "status": "success",
        "final_response": 1,
        "payload": {
            "diagnostic_info": {
                "adk_dialog_manager_status": "undefined",
                "nlu_version": "[NLU_PROJECT:NVCCP-eng-USA];[Datapack:Version: nlps-eng-USA-NVCCP-6.1.100.12-2-GMT20151130160932];[VL-Models:Version: vlmodels-NVCCP-eng-USA-6.1.100.12-2-GMT20151130160335]",
                "nlps_host": "mt-dmz-nlps002..com:8636",
                "nlps_ip": "10.56.10.51",
                "application": "AUDI_2017",
                "nlu_component_flow": "[Input:VoiceJSON] [FieldID|auto_main] [NLUlib|C-eckart-r$Rev$.f20151118.1250] [build|G-r72490M.f20151130.1055] [vlmodel|Version: vlmodels-NVCCP-eng-USA-6.1.100.12-2-GMT20151130160335] [Flow|+VlingoTokenized]",
                "third_party_delay": "0",
                "nmaid": "AUDI_SDS_2017_EXT_20151203",
                "nlps_profile": "AUDI_2017",
                "fieldId": "auto_main",
                "nlps_profile_package_version": "r159218",
                "nlu_annotator": "com.NVCCP.eng-GBR.ncs51.VlingoNLU-client-qNVCCP_NCS51",
                "ext_map_time": "2",
                "nlu_use_literal_annotator": "0",
                "int_map_time": "2",
                "nlps_nlu_type": "nlu_project",
                "nlu_language": "eng-GBR",
                "timing": {
                    "finalRespSentDelay": "188",
                    "intermediateRespSentDelay": "648"
                },
                "nlps_profile_package": "AUDI_2017"
            },
            "actions": [{
                "Input": {
                    "Interpretations": ["ConnectedDrive"],
                    "Type": "asr"
                },
                "Instances": [{
                    "nlu_classification": {
                        "Domain": "UDE",
                        "Intention": "Unspecified"
                    },
                    "nlu_interpretation_index": 1,
                    "nlu_slot_details": {
                        "Name": {
                            "literal": "ConnectedDrive"
                        },
                        "Search-phrase": {
                            "literal": "connecteddrive"
                        }
                    },
                    "interpretation_confidence": 4549
                }],
                "type": "nlu_results",
                "api_version": "1.0"
            }],
            "nlps_version": "nlps(z):6.1.100.12.2-B359;Version: nlps-base-Zeppelin-6.1.100-B124-GMT20151130193521;"
        }
    },
    "final_response": 1,
    "prompt": "",
    "result_format": "appserver_post_results"
}----_NMSP_vutc5w1XobDdefsYG3wq--
```

---

CODE:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys
import time
import webbrowser
from io import BytesIO
import uuid
import httplib
import StringIO
import re
import difflib
import mmap
import json

directory =os.path.join("C:\Users\Desktop\Working\pcm-audio\English")
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(directory): 
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".txt"): 
            content=json.load(file)
            if "status_code" in content:
              if content["status_code"]==0:
                print("valid")
```

I am reading a `.txt` file from a specific path as above. Later I am checking for only `status_code` in the `.txt` file.

If it is 0 then I am printing as valid else Invalid. Later I am looking for transcriptions and Interpretations variable in the `.txt` file (I showed in the beginning, what it contains), which has a list of values.

Comparing those values, I compared it but I am not getting output. I am making a mistake with RegEx here: `if line.find("transcriptions") == ("Interpretations"):`

`status_code` is working fine. But not the `transcriptions` and `Interpretations`.

Can someone tell me what is the mistake here?

Comment: what actually `find` will do?

Comment: finds the variable. In my case transcriptions and Interpretations

Comment: It's a bit unclear for me, but are you trying to compare values for "transcriptions" field and "Interpretations"? In your code shouldn't be
      
   if line.find("transcriptions") == line.find("Interpretations")

to do the correct compare?

I'm a very neewby in python...:)

Comment: yes. what you said is exactly right. But first I want to find those fields from the .txt file then I have to compare.

Comment: I still can't get what is the issue, sorry. You're trying to matching if the array of "Interpretations" is equal to the "transcriptions" one? Or if it's at least a subset?

Comment: there are "transcriptions" and "Interpretations": as shown in my code but it is in the .txt file. I did not add the complete .txt file. I want to find these two fields from the .txt file and compare those two fields to check the first element of transcriptions is equal to interpretations.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Searching in a .txt file and Comparing the two values of a string in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34393596/searching-in-a-txt-file-and-comparing-the-two-values-of-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Without details on the implementation of find this is diffictult to answer.

I would propose a completely different approach. The input you are reading looks like valid JSON. Why not just load this with pythons json module. This will give you a python dict with a very nice interface.

```
import json
info=json.load("filename.txt")
if "status" in info:
  print(info["status"])
```

JSON has full support for arrays. You can add validation quite easily

```
if "actions" in info:
  value=info["actions"]
  if not isinstance(value, list):
    raise TypeException("expecting a list of actions")
```

I would avoid using regular expressions. Right now the regex you are using is easy to read but if your input parsing becomes more sophisticated, this will surely change. Regexes are good for validation but I wouldn't try to parse JSON with them.

Mind the difference between `json.loads` and `json.load`. Loads will try to parse a string, load will read a file.

**EDIT:**
I've read up on find. It seems to return a boolean. You shouldn't compare that to a string. In python 3 this will always be false. This could be a problem in your code.

**EDIT2:**
Reading a list of files:

```
filenames=["a.txt","b.txt","c.json","d.asdadf"] 
for filename in filenames:   
  content = json.load(filename)   
  if "status" in content:
    print(filename+" contains a status entry")
    status_entry=content["status"]
    print("it is: "+str(status_entry))   
  else:
    print(filename+" does not contain a status entry")
```

With your setup, this should probably look like this, but I haven't tested that yet:

```
directory =os.path.join("C:\Users\hemanth_venkatappa\Desktop\Working\pcm-audio\English")
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(directory): 
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".txt"): 
            content=json.load(file)
            if "status_code" in content:
              if content["status_code"]==0:
                print("valid")
```

You can use glob to get the filenames:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html

```
import glob
glob.glob("path_to_folder/*.txt")
```

will return a list of filenames, like this

```
["path_to_folder/a.txt", "path_to_folder/asdief.txt"]
```

You can use this list in the code above.
Just be aware of supplying the correct path to the folder.
Python has a current working directory. The path needs to be relative to this directory.

Take a look at os.getcwd() to get the current working directory and os.chdir() to change it.

**Edit:**

The file is the result of some web query. It says

> Content-type : application/json

But of course the json parser will not be able to read that file. You didn't include the output of your program, but I assume that json.load fails. The error method should be something like "The file doesn't contain valid json" . That's because you have the headers of the (http?)-response included in the file. They need to be removed.
You could do that manually, you could use python, maybe with a regex. But the best way to do that would be not to store the headers in the first place. Where do you generate the file ? I think you should tweak that code first.

Honestly, I don't think you're really working on this. You just pasted my code and didn't reflect on what you're doing. Read up on JSON, use a debugger and look at each line of your code, think about the error message.

Comment: thank you. But there will be several .txt file. I want to read one after the other. How can I do that ?

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem. If you have a list of the files, you can just load them into a dictionary one after the other. Then you can check for existence of "status" in each of the dicts.

Comment: can you please tell me how to load the .txt file one after the other into the dictionary ?

Comment: If there is a folder with several .wav and .txt file in that. So how can I read only .txt file from that specific folder by specifying the path of the folder?

Comment: There's a very nice python module for that: glob. It can give you a list of filenames that match some unix pattern. Adding code to the answer, just a second

Comment: getting the error as : return loads(fp.read(),
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: well then fp is already a string. are you calling that on a filename ? you have to open the file first: file=open("filename") then file.read(). and all of that is not necessary. just give the filename to json.load

Comment: i have to go now. have fun with python

Comment: can I have your email id ? I will write you there !! You can reply me when ever you are free.

Comment: Yeah sure, what would be your preferred method of billing ?

Comment: This is a QA site, not a paid peer review service.

Comment: I am a student. I needed some suggestions from you. Sorry.

Comment: How? you said you changed your code, but it's still the same. Edit your question and include the complete program, the complete folder structure, the content of all important files and the output of your program, then i'll see what I can do.